# Apache Server Monitoring

Tags: web-server, server, monitoring

I'm making a local server for a database in RPI. I just followed typical tutorials out there to install Apache, MySQL, PHP. Now, I want to make the server to output logs to a tft lcd i have. Basically, whenever something happens (someone accesses the rpi through browser, etc) it will output logs to the lcd.

So far, i made the lcd work and a terminal is shown on the lcd. I'm stuck now how to make the server log to the lcd.

How would i make the server log events to the terminal or to a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
tail -f <file>
```

to output the end of, and `f`ollow new writes to, a text file.

You probably want to follow `/var/log/apache/access.log` (but the location may vary, check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored)

So,

```
tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log
```

should probably output any new (access) log messages to your terminal.